# FLUTTER - Mapping part of a list into Widgets

Tags: list, flutter

I am working on an ANAGRAM Game Screen. The idea is to shuffle the letters of a word and make them into separate draggable boxes.
For now, I have succeeded in mapping my list of letters into widgets (LetterBox).
Here is the code :

```
 Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    var uD = Provider.of<UdProvider>(context);
    List letters = widget.word!.split("");
    letters.shuffle();
    print(letters);
    return Scaffold(
      backgroundColor: Colors.indigo[900],
             body: Row(children: [
        ...letters.map((e) => Expanded(child: LetterBox(letter: e))),
      ]),
    );
```

It works fine, but I am encountering a problem. If the word has too many letters, it will eventually raise a problem for my row. What would be great is to display a maximum of 7 letters per row in a kind of column if the word is longer than 7.
Is there a way to map part of the list into a row and the rest into another row ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You might want to have a look at [GridView](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/widgets/GridView-class.html). With the `GridView.count` constructor, you can specify how many items you want to display in one direction (horizontal by default), before adding another row.

```
GridView.count(
  crossAxisCount: 7,
  children: [...letters.map((e) => LetterBox(letter: e))]),
),
```

Comment: Yes, that seems interesting. We can use GridView and Draggable together ?

Comment: I honestly don't have a lot of experience with `Draggable`, but I don't see a reason why those shouldn't work together